# Sumar todos los campos de una misma columna de varios registros MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla con varios registros, y digamos que cada uno recoge las visitas que tiene (por ejemplo). ¿Cómo puedo **obtener el total** de visitas?

Pero no de todos, sino de los que cumplan una condición. Es decir, si tengo:

```
| Cat       | Visitas |
-----------------------
| Juegos    | 12      |
| Juegos    | 7       |
| Programas | 23      |
```

¿Cómo hago para obtener la suma de `visitas` de todos los registros cuya entrada sea `Juegos`?

De momento lo único que tengo hecho es la conexión mySQL:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername1, $username1, $password1, $dbname1);
$reg = mysqli_query($conn,
    "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE cat='$cat'")
or die( "Error al conectar con la base de datos 2: " . mysqli_error($conn) );
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero sería crear la conexión y después tendrías que hacer la consulta usando `SUM()` de `PHP` para que te devolviera la suma. Entonces quedaría algo así.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");

/* comprobar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$resultado = $mysqli->query('SELECT SUM(Visitas) FROM tabla WHERE Categoría = "jugador"');
$result = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $result;

?>
```

Y esto sería todo.

Comment: Una vez adaptado a mi código, me aparece el siguiente error `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string` El error se origina al hacer el `echo`

Comment: Se me ha olvidado meter la línea de obtener los datos.